# Instance from collection controlling in render layers

Tags: collections, instances, viewlayers

Is it possible to disable an 'instance' from a collection in View Layer?
I don't see the option there.
Right now, my instances stay visible in all my rendered layers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instanced collections are actually empty objects acting as a proxy for another  collection.

[image]

They behave like all the other objects in relation to view layers, so you will have to put them in their own sub-collection to exclude them from a view layer.

[image]

Comment: Amazing. So simple, but I would have never thought of that. (Tried to disable the Collection inside the instance though, but these are greyed out. Thank you!

Comment: Great, I was looking for that 'answer check box', found it. Thanks!